# What's the meaning of closemouthed in the context?

Tags: word-meaning

> "Tom", Michael Corleone said, "I'm driving down to the city with Kay
>   tommorow. There's something important I want to tell the old man
>   before Christmas. Will he be home tommorow night?"
>
> "Sure," Hagen said "He's not going out of town until after Christmas.
>   Anything I can do for you?"
>
> Michael was as **closemouthed** as his father. "No," he said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closemouthed can generally mean that the person was ***not*** talking at all. Or it can mean that a person is talking, *most people need to open their mouth to talk*, but just not speaking of the details or not giving out very much information.

In this case, it seems that Michael and the father were *up to something*, and didn't want Hagen to know what they were *up to*. Which is why he just answered *No* when Hagen asked if there was anything he could do for him.